# Report all non used elements (+attributes) of corresponding schema

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, saxon, xslt-3.0

*In this topic, I want to ask much more brain cells than I can offer on my own. I would like to refactor my XSD (v1.0) depending on the used/not used elements in real XML instances (single namespaces only). Let's build up a small **scenario**:*

I have only valid XML documents against a corresponding schema:

```
<body>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p><bold>bold</bold>paragraph<italic>italic</italic></p>
</body>
```

XSD to validate against:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="body">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="h1"/>
        <xs:element ref="h2"/>
        <xs:element ref="p"/>
        <xs:element ref="span"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="h1" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="h2" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="p">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="bold"/>
        <xs:element ref="italic"/>
        <xs:element ref="underline"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="span">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="bold"/>
        <xs:element ref="italic"/>
        <xs:element ref="underline"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="bold" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="italic" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="underline" type="xs:NCName"/>
</xs:schema>
```

On this base, I would like to create a report (via XSLT [2.0, 3.0 via SAXON EE 9.6.0.5 available]) about which elements (tags + attributes) are **NOT** used in my XML instances but are possible in my XSD.

**simplified pseudo todos / Starting from scratch:**

- search for all `//xs:element[@name]` (attributes follow in report v2.0) in my XSD.
- search for all `*` in my XML
- "compare" it

**Questions:**

Is there something beyond my horizon about this topic in the lovely XSLT community already?

*How to store and compare it in a good manner?*

Use `xsl:map` via XSLT 3.0? Store paths [`/body/h1`,`/body/p`] and compare these paths? (tricky: get the correct paths out of the schema, handle all ways of definitions, like `xs:group ref="..."` or via `complexTypes` etc.)

[AddOn: Maybe I have to extend it to the context of ancestor elements in my XML. In the example case, I might want to 
distinguish between `//p/underline` and `//span/underline`.]

`<xsl:message>please write your thoughts open minded. I don't request for fully functional code!</xsl:message>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post reminded me of an option on the com.saxonica.Validate command: by specifying -stats:report.xml you are supposed to get a report on the usage of schema components within your instance document. It appears to be not working in 9.7 (and I've raised a bug on that), but with 9.5 you get a report of the form:

```
<schemaCoverage>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="PUB-DATE" count="6"/>
   <component kind="complexType" namespace="" name="weightType" count="6"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="PUBLISHER" count="6"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="AUTHOR" count="6"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="DIMENSIONS" count="6"/>
   <component kind="simpleType" namespace="" name="languageType" count="6"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="QUANTITY" count="6"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="CATEGORY" count="3"/>
   <component kind="complexType"
              namespace="http://ns.saxonica.com/anonymous-type"
              name="CATEGORIES_anonymous_type_1_at_line_23_of_books.xsd"
              count="1"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="LANGUAGE" count="6"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="PAGES" count="6"/>
   <component kind="complexType" namespace="" name="moneyType" count="6"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="ISBN" count="6"/>
   <component kind="simpleType"
              namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              name="IDREF"
              count="6"/>
   <component kind="simpleType"
              namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              name="ID"
              count="3"/>
   <component kind="complexType"
              namespace="http://ns.saxonica.com/anonymous-type"
              name="BOOKS_anonymous_type_1_at_line_14_of_books.xsd"
              count="1"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="CATEGORIES" count="1"/>
   <component kind="simpleType" namespace="" name="ISBNType" count="6"/>
   <component kind="simpleType"
              namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              name="string"
              count="22"/>
   <component kind="complexType"
              namespace="http://ns.saxonica.com/anonymous-type"
              name="ITEM_anonymous_type_1_at_line_39_of_books.xsd"
              count="6"/>
   <component kind="simpleType" namespace="" name="weightUnitType" count="6"/>
   <component kind="complexType"
              namespace="http://ns.saxonica.com/anonymous-type"
              name="CATEGORY_anonymous_type_1_at_line_31_of_books.xsd"
              count="3"/>
   <component kind="simpleType"
              namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              name="date"
              count="6"/>
   <component kind="simpleType"
              namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              name="integer"
              count="12"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="TITLE" count="6"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="PRICE" count="6"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="WEIGHT" count="6"/>
   <component kind="complexType" namespace="" name="dimensionsType" count="6"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="ITEM" count="6"/>
   <component kind="simpleType" namespace="" name="lengthUnitType" count="6"/>
   <component kind="element" namespace="" name="BOOKS" count="1"/>
</schemaCoverage>
```

This seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Look into http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/type.html and http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/schema.html to get schema type information in Saxon EE on your nodes, that is hopefully a way to compare your instance to the schema. I have never used that so I am not sure how far you will get, I am sure if you add the [saxon](/questions/tagged/saxon) to your question then Michael Kay will give you some better insights in due course.

Comment: Thanks so far, added the tag for mighty Dr. Kay.

Answer (score 1):

I did an exercise a bit like this for the XSLT 3.0 test suite. You can find the stylesheet here:

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xslt30-test/file/24e8b98b044b/tests/misc/catalog/catalog-007.xsl

It takes two inputs:

(a) the SCM file generated using com.saxonica.Validate with the -scmout option, applied to the schema-for-xslt30. The SCM file is a representation of the compiled schema, which is much easier to analyze from XSLT than the original source schema

(b) the set of non-error stylesheets in the test suite, obtained by searching through the test metadata catalog recursively.

It extracts the set of element-name/attribute-name pairs permitted by the schema, and then extracts the set of element-name/attribute-name pairs actually present in the stylesheets (in each case filtered, e.g. to consider only elements in the XSLT namespace). It then compares the two lists, and reports any pairs permitted by the schema that are not present in a test stylesheet, as well as any pairs present in a test stylesheet that are not permitted by the schema. The test passes only if both lists are empty.